# Request to external service times out on Heroku web process but works in console process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, timeout, puma

I have a Rails 4 application running on Heroku. For one type of request I make a HTTP call to an external service and then return the response to the client.

As I see from the logs, the request to the external service is taking too long and resulting in the Heroku's H12 error where it sends a 503 after 30 seconds. The HTTP request that I am making to the external service eventually comes back with a Net::ReadTimeout after some more time (60 seconds).

However if I run `heroku run console` and make the same HTTP call (through the same Ruby code), it works just fine. The request completes in about a second or two at the max.

I am unable to understand why this request is timing out when run from the web process while it works seamlessly in the `heroku run console`.

I am running Puma as my webserver. I followed guidelines given here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server
I also tried the basic WEBrick server to see if that helps. But no avail.

Has anyone faced this issue? Any hints on how to debug this?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue but on a dedicated server. I'm also running puma, so it may be related to the web server and not to Heroku.

Comment: @PabloB. In my case it was an issue with the external service itself. Neither Heroku nor Puma is at fault here. When I was trying it from the heroku console, I was not going through the same code path at the service side which made it appear that the calls are going through. In your case, try extensive logging to figure what is different when the external request is made from the console and your server process. That will tell you where the problem is. Happy to help if you have more questions.